# Is it possible to capture memory paging requests in Windows?

Tags: windows, memory-management

Is there any way to hook into the Windows memory manager to capture paging events - in order to load pages from a custom source/location?

From the links I've found online, it seems that this is not possible in Windows, to do robustly or correctly.
Would a library e.g. EasyHook or similar - be the best way to approach this?

Comment: No, page faults are handled by the kernel in ring 0.

Comment: Thanks Hans - I thought so. How about by running apps in a lightweight vm? I've never seen a successful application virtualization on windows due to several complications, but there's always hope :)

Comment: In principle, if you were to create a virtual disk driver the end user could configure the computer to put the page file on the virtual disk.  I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, though.

Comment: I'm looking at ways to provision apps to windows on demand for my virtual labs. So if the memory manager can redirect to a deduped local & remote cache of memory pages then it can stream them down via spdy/http/socket.io etc

Comment: I would expect it to be more sensible to present the OS with one or more virtual disks containing the application(s) to run.

Comment: I think that is the best tactic as well. Thanks Harry